# Implementing data from text file (Maze)

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

So I'm working on a project for one of my classes, and there's a method we need to implement:

```
public void readMazeFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException,FileNotFoundException, MazeReadException {}
```

As the name implies, we need to read a .txt file and set up our maze accordingly. The file's data is stored like this:

```
5,5 //row, col for maze
Square,0,0,true,false,false,true,true,true //Object, row, col, other values
Square,0,1,true,false,true,false,true,true
Square,0,2,true,false,true,false,false,false
Square,0,3,true,false,false,false,false,false
Square,0,4,true,true,false,false,false,false
Square,1,0,false,false,true,true,true,true
Square,1,1,true,false,true,false,true,true
Square,1,2,true,true,false,false,false,false
Square,1,3,false,true,false,true,false,false
Square,1,4,false,true,false,true,false,false
Square,2,0,true,false,false,true,false,false
Square,2,1,true,false,true,false,false,false
Square,2,2,false,true,false,false,false,false
Square,2,3,false,true,false,true,false,false
Square,2,4,false,true,false,true,false,false
Square,3,0,false,true,false,true,false,false
Square,3,1,true,false,false,true,false,false
Square,3,2,false,true,false,false,false,false
Square,3,3,false,true,true,true,false,false
Square,3,4,false,true,false,true,false,false
Square,4,0,false,true,true,true,false,false
Square,4,1,false,true,true,true,false,false
Square,4,2,false,false,true,true,false,false
Square,4,3,true,false,true,false,false,false
Square,4,4,false,true,true,false,false,false
Explorer,0,0,Scary Name
Treasure,4,4,true
Treasure,2,2,false
Monster,4,4
Monster,3,3
```

The method that I've implemented is not working for some reason. When I run a test driver provided by my instructor, it says I have a nullPointerException in line 239 (`maze.squares[r][c] = new Square(r, c);`)

```
public void readMazeFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, MazeReadException {
    Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    int lineNum = 0;
    while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanFile.nextLine();
        Scanner parsed = new Scanner(line).useDelimiter(",");

        Maze maze = new Maze();

        if (lineNum == 0) {
            if (!parsed.hasNextInt()) {
                throw new MazeReadException("Rows and columns not specified", line, lineNum);
            }

            maze.rows = parsed.nextInt();
            maze.cols = parsed.nextInt();

            maze.squares = new Square[maze.rows][maze.cols];

        }
        while (parsed.hasNext()) {
            if (parsed.next().equals("Square")) {
                int r = parsed.nextInt();
                int c = parsed.nextInt();
                maze.squares[r][c] = new Square(r, c);
                maze.squares[r][c].toObject(parsed);
            } else {
                if (parsed.next().equals("Explorer")) {
                    maze.explorer = new Explorer(maze);
                    maze.explorer.toObject(parsed);
                } else if (parsed.next().equals("Treasure")) {
                    Treasure t = new Treasure(maze);
                    t.toObject(parsed);
                    maze.randOccupants.add(t);
                    //maze.randOccupants.get(maze.randOccupants.indexOf(t)).toObject(parsed);
                } else if (parsed.next().equals("Monster")) {
                    Monster m = new Monster(maze);
                    m.toObject(parsed);
                    maze.randOccupants.add(m);
                    //maze.randOccupants.get(maze.randOccupants.indexOf(m)).toObject(parsed);
                }
            }
        }
        parsed.close();
        lineNum++;
    }
    scanFile.close();
}
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: You haven't initialized all your arrays.

Comment: Instead of "deleting" the question, you should post the solution for future reference. Someone might have the same problem...

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ - in particular, a debugger will help you here.

Answer (score 1):

In your default constructor of Maze, you need to initialize squares. Something like this:

```
public Maze() {
  this.squares = new Square[DIM_X][DIM_Y];// max dimesions of the maze
  // same for the other arrays
}
```

Comment: I have that set already. Sorry I'm unable to post my entire code, it's too large most likely. The problem is within this method.